# Building georeferenced GeoTIFF from mbtiles automatically?

Tags: raster, georeferencing, imagery, mbtiles

I want a georeferenced raster.In that way I don't have to georeference this raster manually .
I know that geotiff has the georeference inside it , I got the mbtiles of the map how do I build the georeferenced geotiff.

my mbtile [mbtile file](http://dartotalsolutions.scienceontheweb.net/zoom13.mbtiles) tronsform it to Geotiff

Comment: Search for raster world file format. See featured questions for a clue

Comment: Just use `gdal_translate`. If you edit the question with the exact name of the mbtiles file, and the name you'd like the geotiff output to have, I can paste an answer.

Comment: I installed Gdal I used the command gdal_translate zoom13.mbtiles export.tiff but my export.tiff is not georeferenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something like:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff zoom13.mbtiles export.tiff`

The reason for the `-of GTiff` part is that the default output is TIFF, with external georeferencing, rather than GeoTIFF. See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

If you want to rebuild the overviews (similar to what you probably have in mbtiles), `gdaladdo` will probably help: http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html